# how does laravel's bootstrap/cache/services.php work?

Tags: php, laravel

I've thoroughly searched the web for an answer to this, but there doesn't seem to be any documentation on this:

When and how does laravel's `bootstrap/cache/services.php` get generated? I can see that all service providers are collected here, together with the information if they are deferred and if they are bound contextually.

Now, what happens if I move a ServiceProvider in my application to another namespace? Then the reference in the `services.php` would be wrong, right? Does it automatically get regenerated then? Or do I have to manually erase it? And if so, is there an artisan command that does this? `cache:clear` doesn't seem to do the trick.

Thanks in advance!
Christoph